# Asp.net core model doesn't bind from form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, asp.net-core, model-binding

I catch post request from 3rd-side static page (generated by Adobe Muse) and handle it with MVC action.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="Name">
   ...
</form>
```

Routing for empty form action:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute(
   name: "default",
   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"));
```

But in according action I have model with every property is empty

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Index(EmailModel email)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Sending email");
}
```

Model:

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Additional { get; set; }
}
```

`Request.Form` has all values from form, but model is empty

```
[0] {[Name, Example]}
[1] {[Email, Example@example.com]}
[2] {[Company, Hello]}
[3] {[Phone, Hello]}
[4] {[Additional, Hello]}
```

Comment: Why do you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? You don't need to specify this because your model doesn't contain any file upload. Probably your problem causes from this. Remove and try.

Comment: @ademcaglin removed `enctype` attribute. Doesn't help. Still `Request.Form` has all values, but `model` is empty.

Comment: Did you use any javascript code to send form?

Comment: @ademcaglin no, just pure form submit

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Be careful not to give an action parameter a name that is the same as a model property or the binder will attempt to bind to the parameter and fail.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index( EmailModel email ){ ... }

public class EmailModel{ public string Email { get; set; } }
```

Change the actions parameter 'email' to a different name and it will bind as expected.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index( EmailModel uniqueName ){ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a property named "Model" in my view model which broke the binding.

Comment: Seems like ASP.NET Core's model binding code could throw us a bone by maybe throwing an exception in this case!

Comment: I mean... Wow.. This is something I couldn't find on my own.

Comment: You are my angel!

Comment: Well, that's an hour of pointless debugging I'm never getting back.

Comment: ARE YOU KIDDING ME?! I lost HOURS to this /tableflip. THANK YOU

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure it is same case, but I had same problem and nothing really looks to work for me.
The problem in my case was that I had a property called Model in my view model class

```
public string Model { get; set; }
```

When I renamed the property to ModelName everything was working fine again, even without FromForm attribute.

Looks like some special property names could be a bit of a problem for asp.net mvc model binding.

So, my advice is to check your model properties and maybe try renaming them one by one in order to check if the problem is there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net Core 3.1

In my case, I was using a complex model (a model that contains other models, like a shared model) posted by Ajax, so the inputs in the view were automatically named like this "ChildModel.PropertyName" (see code)

```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] // ("AUVM.PropertyName")
   public async Task<JsonResult> AddUser([FromForm]AUVM aUVM) //Parameter name must match the first part of the input name in order to bind
   {

   }
```

```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<JsonResult> AddUser([FromForm]AUVM someUniqueName) //This is wrong and won't bind
   {

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem
this docs helps me to understand Model Binding
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html

I solved my problem by making sure that the property name is exact match in form field name
and I also add [FromForm] attribute to specify exactly the binding source.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today, and though in hindsight it seems obvious, just thought I'd add that you need to make sure your access modifiers for the Properties on the model you're binding are correct.  I had `public MyProperty { get; internal set; }` on some and they would not bind.  Removed `internal` and they worked just fine.

Comment: OMG that's the problem I had.  I would have never figured this out without your awesome help. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Change *void* to *ActionResult*.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(EmailModel email)
```

And don't forget verifying AntiForgeryToken from your view and action.

```
// to your form in view 
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
// ------------

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(EmailModel email)
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Also I can't use `AntiForgeryToken` because this page is not mine and generated by 3rd party tools (Adobe Muse)

Comment: I think you can't get it as model with a tool which is not in action view. You can try to get value with form get method, and not as a model. By paramater names. Index(string Name, String Email, String Company, String Phone). And convert this values to your object model in procedure.

Comment: I also think mvc can't find model or something, and yes I can just use a bunch of action parameters, or fill it with `Request.Form` in action, or try to do that with `IModelBinder`, I just want to understand why I can't just use default model binding. Maybe I missed some conventions?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also happen if one or more of your properties in the request model fail to bind into an acceptable on the request model.

In my case, I was supposed to pass a `List<string>` type to a property, but accidentally passed a `string`. This resulted in the entire request model becoming `null`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the MVC 4.0 convention of naming the object you are posting. E.g.,

> js: `$http.post("SaveAnswer", { answer: answerValues })`
>
> C#: `public ActionResult SaveAnswer([FromBody] AnswerVM answer) {...}`

When I changed the js to `$http.post("SaveAnswer", answerValues)`, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I have run in to this issue where the model does not bind when I have more than one constructor on the underlying model like:

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public EmailModel()
    {}

    public EmailModel(string _name, string _company)
    {
        Name = _name;
        Company = _company;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Additional { get; set; }
}
```

Fixed by removing all but one constructor like this:

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public EmailModel()
    {}

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Additional { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I want to share what happened in my case and how I got the solution. Perhaps, someone may find it useful to know.

My context was ***ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor pages***.
I had a handler as

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostLogin([FromForm] LoginInput loginData)
{
  
}
```

and also I had a property in my ViewModel as

```
  public LoginInput LoginInput { get; set; }
```

And in my Razor page, I have used the form like this:

```
 <form asp-page-handler="Login" method="post">

 <input asp-for="LoginData.UserNameOrEmail">

 .....
```

So, notice that, in my form, I used the property **LoginInput.UserNameOrEmail**, but in my handler's parameter, I used the parameter name **loginData**. How will the ASP.NET Core know that, this **LoginInput.UserNameOrEmail** is actually **loginData.UserNameOrEmail**. It can't, right? Therefore, it did not bind my form data.

Then, when I renamed my ViewModel property "**LoginInput**" to the same name as the handler parameter, like this:

```
public LoginInput LoginData { get; set; }
```

The ASP.NET Core then found that the form data was matching the parameter name and then it started to bind properly. My problem was solved.